# Null Reference by a DataRow

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I get a null - reference in this Code-line:**

```
 **DataRow dr = tableSelectedItems.NewRow();**
```

I can't find out why. Can anyone help me please?
My code should fill the books which were Selected by the user in a datalist. This is to learn how Sessionstate works. I used the book "ASP.NET 3.5 Step by Step" in a German version. I have exactly the same code as them, but i'm using .net 4.0 instead of 3.5.
Can please someone help me??
All the code of the DatalistItemdCommand is:

```
      protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int nItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        this.DataList1.SelectedIndex = nItemIndex;

        BindToinventory();

        //Row's Order: ID, Title, FirstName, LastName, Topic, Publisher

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)DataList1.DataSource;
        string strID = (dt.Rows[nItemIndex][0]).ToString();
        string strTitle = (dt.Rows[nItemIndex][1]).ToString();
        string strAuthorLastName = (dt.Rows[nItemIndex][2]).ToString();
        string strAuthorFirstName = (dt.Rows[nItemIndex][3]).ToString();
        string strTopic = (dt.Rows[nItemIndex][4]).ToString();
        string strPublisher = (dt.Rows[nItemIndex][5]).ToString();

        DataTable tableSelectedItems;
        tableSelectedItems = (DataTable)Session["tableSelectedItems"];

        //Null Reference is here
        DataRow dr = tableSelectedItems.NewRow();
        dr[0] = strID;
        dr[1] = strTitle;
        dr[2] = strAuthorLastName;
        dr[3] = strAuthorFirstName;
        dr[4] = strTopic;
        dr[5] = strPublisher;

        tableSelectedItems.Rows.Add(dr);

        Session["tableSelectedItems"] = tableSelectedItems;

        this.GridView1.DataSource = tableSelectedItems;
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: seems `tableSelectedItems` is null in your case, are you assigning anything to Session["tableSelectedItems"] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to use the session with out first set a value to it / or the value to this session is not the same data type. I suggest to change to this code:

```
DataTable tableSelectedItems;
object otabSelItems  = Session["tableSelectedItems"];

if(otabSelItems is DataTable)
   tableSelectedItems = (DataTable)otabSelItems;
else
   tableSelectedItems = new DataTable();
```

how ever you must have in mind that this variable will always be null **if the user did not have set cookie enable**, or the session have time outs.

Why the session will be always null if the cookie is off ? because the session variables are associate with the cookie. If the user have cookies off, then in every reload a new cookie is created and the application can not know the previous cookie, and can not connect the previous session with this user and creates a new session.

Comment: Yes, it were the cookies. Thank you so much. I didn't thought about them.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableSelectedItems = (DataTable)Session["tableSelectedItems"];
```

This line may be the problem because if session["tableSelectedItems"] is null then tableSelectedItems will also be null.

Answer (score 0):

@Aristos is right.. also other guyz too..its a simple check..
my opinion is to add this line too

**tableSelectedItems.AcceptChanges();**

after you add the row in table..i.e
tableSelectedItems.Rows.Add(dr);